# data Frame to csv file not including the numbers (floats in the table) and cleaning '\n'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Am trying to save a data frame in pandas to csv file however the numbers in the table are not getting written to the file [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaC6Z.png)

also even after doing replace to clean out the '\n' from the table it is still not working

```
final_product = income_df2.replace('[\n$,)]','', regex=True )\
                     .replace( '[(]','-', regex=True)\
                     .replace( '', 'NaN', regex=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace **\n** in each column, and cast the column **to numeric**

```
final_product =  pd.to_numeric(income_df2.replace('\n', '',regex=True))
```

if you need, replace any NaN with some value (in this case, 0)

```
final_product.fillna(0)
```